# Can you change set a Big Object?

Tags: metadata-api, change-set, object, big-object

I am trying to change set a big object from my developer sandbox to a full sandbox.

I have [seen here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object_define.htm) in the dev notes that it can be done via the metadata api.  But nothing about changesets.

So I attempted this and got the error

> Indexes required. Custom Big Objects without indexes aren't allowed.

I included the index field and all other fields on the object in the changeset.

Anyone got a helpful article on this. I havent found much besides the afore mentioned dev notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot** deploy Big Objects using Change Sets. Anything that can be deployed using Change Sets is documented at [Components Available in Change Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=changesets_about_components.htm&type=5). Anything that you don't see there is not supported.

The only available option that is available as of today is using Metadata API.

Comment: This answer is dead wrong, and should not be the accepted one. Please see [the correct answer here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/292643/89720)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can deploy big objects using Change sets, you just need to find the index in "view/add dependencies"

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer. Custom big objects (as they are called in the Metadata API) are just a very special kind of custom object and listed among these when adding components to change sets. Their indexes are to be found via their dependencies. It appears like a bug that indexes of big objects are not listed along with the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

Elivelton has the correct answer, to add more:
I had to click View/Add Dependencies, then use that painfull navigation to reach for the **Custom Index** AND the **Custom Fields** for the big object. Then the change set works.